# Package vagrant box to location

Tags: vagrant

I want to package a box file to a location as my disk is nearly full, does anyone know how to accomplish this.

I am running the `vagrant package` command

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save space on your disk and you do not need to delete/recreate the VM, you can simply delete the box.

Indeed when running `vagrant up`, vagrant clones the current box file as the VM and do not need it afterwards. even if you delete the base box, vagrant will continue working as normal. Only in case you need to delete your VM and recreate and provision as a new VM, you will need the base box again.